# Stack allocation in c++ for large sizes

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm trying to load a whole lot of primitives using Direct3D 9, so I need to pass a large array of struct to virtual buffer. But if I do it with `malloc()`, my `sizeof()` function returns a wrong value (always 4). And if I typically allocate stack memory (`array[number]`), stack can overflow because of number of elements.
Is there any alternative to it? How do I allocate stack memory that can load as much data?

P.S. I'm not gonna draw them all to the screen, but I still need their vertex information.

Comment: Use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or keep track of the size yourself.

Comment: In case you are wondering why you always get 4, you are taking the sizeof a pointer to the array: not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with a pointer, the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

When you allocate memory dynamically (in C++ use `new` instead of `malloc`) you need to keep track of the amount of entries yourself. Or better yet, use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Why does sizeof work properly when it comes to stack non-dynamic arrays then?

Comment: @user2999436 Because then the compiler actually *have* the size of the array, e.g. the number of items multiplied with the size of the arrays type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with `malloc()` and then using `sizeof()` will give you 4. That's the pointer size.

If you are just wondering how to fill your values in ptr then refer code below:

> ```
> int numOfItems = 10;
> int* pArr = (malloc(sizeof(int)*numOfItems);
> for (int i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
>     pArr[i] = i+1;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you called malloc, you called it with the size of the amount of space you wanted. If you want to know later on how big the allocation is, you need to keep that information around yourself.

Since your using C++, you could useIf you called malloc, you called it with the size of the amount of space you wanted. If you want to know later on how big the allocation is, you need to keep that information around yourself.

If that's too much trouble, since your using C++, you could use a `<vector>` or similar, which will track its own size. a vector or similar, which will track its own size.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to allocate a std::vector dynamically and using a smart pointer.

```
std::shared_ptr< std::vector< your data type> > vertices( new std::vector( number );
```

Now you don't overflow the stack, all relevant housekeeping is done by std::vector and std::shared_ptr, and most importantly memory will get deleted.